# Implicit casting from float to integer in C — why not the other way around?

Tags: c

Based on C's implicit casting rule, data types are converted to higher type.

Nerveless when I try:

```
float a; 
int b; 
a = b = 3.4;
```

The output is always an integer number for both `a` and `b`.
Can I know the reason behind this? Why is it not converting `int` to `float`?

Comment: Read up on "chaining assignment"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assignment (`=`) has right-to-left associativity (see [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)) so
`float a; int b; a = b = 3.4;` is the same as:

```
float a;
int b;
b = 3.4; // b is now 3   (since it can only hold integer values)
a = b;   // a is now 3.f
```